# Effect of gauge transformations on connections. Passage in the proof

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory

Given a gauge transformation $u$ for a vector bundle $E\to M$, and a connection $\nabla$, we define: $$u^*\nabla = u\nabla(u^{-1}s)$$

I want to prove the well-known identity $$u^*\nabla = \nabla -(d_{\nabla}u)u^{-1}$$

A passage in the proof I'm following starts by considering:
$$ \nabla s=\nabla(uu^{-1}s)=(d_{\nabla}u)(u^{-1}s)+u\nabla(u^{-1}s)$$

why are we applying the Leibniz rule to the composition $u^{-1}us$? I mean Why are we considering it as a product?

Comment: How are you defining the action of a connection on a gauge transformation if not by the Leibniz rule?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis what do you mean? I gave the definition in the first line, and (in my opinion but I'm by no means an expert) doesn't require the Leibniz rule

Comment: You defined the pullback connection $u^* \nabla,$ still acting on sections of $E$. I want to know how you define the derivative of a gauge transformation, i.e. a section $u$ of $\mathrm{Aut}(E).$ I think most authors would take the Leibniz rule $(d_\nabla u)(s) = \nabla(u(s)) - u(\nabla s)$ as the *definition* of $d_\nabla u.$ This is sensible because gauge transformations are fiber-wise linear, so their composition can be thought of as multiplication of matrix-valued functions.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I see, I guess my professor used directly some sort of Leibniz property (as you pointed out at the end this is sensible) without defining the derivative of a gauge transformation. Can you give me some reference for this?